# Automation system, Database

Tags: database, automation, system

I worked in big project last year, it was Educational Management System! My team solved a lot of problems during developing. But we had one problem and now I am again got it.

Problem is:

> how to design database structure, if some records that have references
>   can be deleted from Software Interface?

Simple Example: Assume that, you have tables :

```
Students, StudentClass, Marks, Classes
```

.  So, if I try to delete record from `'Classes'` table, it will be impossible, because `'StudentClass'` table has reference to `'Classes'` table. Of course, it is possible delete records from depending tables(`StudentClass, etc.`) and then delete `'Classes'` record, but i need to keep data.

I found solution, in all tables that is referenced by other, i create column `'IsDeleted'`.
It means that If i want to delete record from `'Classes'` table, i just update `'IsDeleted'` column to `1`. To show to users, i use `"SELECT * .... FROM ... WHERE Classes.IsDeleted = 0".`

This my solution! Can you tell me, how you solve such problems, share with me your approaches, pls! Any opinions will be interesting for me! Thanks in advance for your reply!!!!

**EDIT:**

Any solutions else?

Comment: We had similar problem sometimes back when contacts could be deleted  but we had to keep the contact details for reports purpose. The approach we took is exactly the same. We added a column deleted to Contacts table. no problem so far :) and like you said it would be interesting to know if someone got a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty classic problem and I've seen your solution implemented many, many times. Often times it is called a "soft" delete because you still have the data in the database, but it won't appear in the UI.

There are two potential drawbacks that come to mind:

1. Developers *always* forget at some point to filter by a deleted flag.
2. The table can grow large if you never delete and at some point this can impact query time.

One potential solution to alleviate both problems is to run a job from time to time that archives/moves the deleted data somewhere else.  You can always query it or restore it later if you want, but it doesn't impact the other "live" records.